# How can I fill out an excel sheet template with data from MySQL with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, excel, pdf

Is there a way I can open an excel template file (.xlsx) via a URL on the server, automatically fill it out with data from the MySQL database and then save it to the user's computer as either excel or pdf file? Where should I start? Thanks for leads!

Comment: A quick google search reveals this library: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've only tried to create my own files directly from the database, but the excel file is going to be submitted to a place where they only accept the original file filled out. That link looks promising, I'm trying it out right now. Thanks!

Comment: @nbayly It seems like it can read my .xlsx file, but I get the following error and a corrupt file generated "Fatal error: Uncaught exception `'PHPExcel_Exception' with message 'Invalid cell coordinate (MAX(MATCH(REPT("Z"' in /Library/WebServer/Documents/sb/Classes/PHPExcel/Cell.php:594 Stack trace: #0..."`. If I use an extremely simple excel file it works, but not with my template file unfortunately. I take it that this script imports and re-creates the whole excel file, it doesn't just alter it and save it?

Comment: I did not review in detail that library so wouldn't be able to answer that. I suggest you close this question down and repost with this specific question and details. Regards

Answer (score 0):

The file would need to be created on the webserver, pulling mysql data and populating the pdf. Then you would create an href link to the file in a secure folder only your users could access. Then later do some kind of file cleanup when user is done with it.
For pdf maybe try this link example: http://www.fpdf.org/en/tutorial/tuto5.htm

Comment: Thanks, I tried that one earlier today, but I need something that can fill out a pre-existing excel file. I'm trying out the PHPExcel library above.